# SVG Segmented Donut Chart Inner Circle Radius

Tags: html, svg

Knowing the `stroke-width` and radius of the outer `<circle>` element, how can the exact radius of the inner `<circle>` be calculated so that it only goes as far as the inner edge of outer `<circle>`? If the radius for the outer `<circle>` was calculated using `r = c / (2π)` with circumference being `100`, is it just a matter of subtracting a certain amount from the circumference? Or would it more effective to create additional `<circle>` elements that would cover extended inner `<circle>`?

A radius of ~`14.5` visually looks really close, but I was hoping to be as exact as possible.

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
  <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="14.45" fill="#fff"></circle>
  <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="3"></circle>

  <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#ce4b99" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="85 15" stroke-dashoffset="0"></circle>
</svg>
```

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: The radius is simply the outer circle's radius minus half the stroke-width. You may have an issue with rounding in some circumstances, though.

Comment: Just to be clear, the "right" value should be 14.41549430918954 here.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That seemed to work really well! If you create an answer documenting the solution, I can mark as it correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radius of the inner edge of your outer circle is quite simply: radius of the outer circle - stroke width / 2.

That's because the stroke is entered on the path being drawn.

So in your example the radius is 14.41549430918954 (15.91549430918954 - 3 / 2).

Note that in some instances there may be rounding errors which may leave a small gap.